# Split string that contains array to get array of values C#

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, split

I have a string that contains an array

```
string str = "array[0]=[1,a,3,4,asdf54,6];array[1]=[1aaa,2,4,k=6,2,8];array[2]=[...]";
```

I'd like to split it to get an array like this:

```
str[0] = "[1,a,3,4,asdf54,6]";
str[1] = "[1aaa,2,4,k=6,2,8]";
str[2] = ....
```

I've tried to use `Regex.Split(str, @"\[\D+\]")` but it didn't work..

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**SOLUTION:**

After seen your answers I used

```
var arr = Regex.Split(str, @"\];array\[[\d, -]+\]=\[");
```

This works just fine, thanks all!

Comment: What's wrong with `string.Split` and `string.Replace`?

Comment: Ur solution doesn't work.it wont split first array properly..also you should mark or at least up vote the answers that have helped u

Comment: -1: Next time, put some more effort into asking the question correctly the first time round. It's a waste of time for contributors to stay updating their answers with each random edit you make to the specification.

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = str.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(new char[]{'='}, 2)).Select(s => s.Last()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is simply elegant.

Comment: Please note that the code does not work correctly for this part of expression: `array[1]=[1aaa,2,4,k=6,2,8]`.

Comment: The question was edited.When I was writing answer,there wasn't this part of expression

Comment: It's probably safe to assume the first equals sign each of the intermediate tokens is the one you want to split on, so this should work `s.Split(new Char[] {'='}, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

In regex, `\d` matches any digit, whilst `\D` matches anything that is *not* a digit. I assume your use of the latter is erroneous. Additionally, you should allow your regex to also match negation signs, commas, and spaces, using the character class `[\d\-, ]`. You can also include a <strike>lookahead</strike> lookbehind for the `=` character, written as `(?<=\=)`, in order to avoid getting the `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, ...

```
string str = "array[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6];array[1]=[1,2,4,6,2,8];array[2]=[...]";
string[] results = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=\=)\[[\d\-, ]+\]")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Great, but now I get: "=[1,2,3,4,5,6];array".
How can I remove also the = and the array in the end?

Comment: @Asaf: I've switched from `Regex.Split` to `Regex.Matches`; this should fix it.

Comment: @Douglas: I get an empty array now

Comment: @Asaf: Could you paste your source string? I get correct results for the snippet above.

Comment: Just seen your edit... If you want to use regex, you need to know the exact format of your strings. You can't just introduce arbitrary items (*HTML tags???*) and expect it to still work.

Comment: +1 for best overall solution--but I would have upvoted you just for switching to `Matches()`. ;)  Just FYI, `(?<=\=)` is a *lookbehind*, not a lookahead, and you don't have to escape the equals sign: `(?<==)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - using regular expression look behind to grab the relevant parts of your string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "array[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6];array[1]=[1,2,4,6,2,8];array[2]=[...]";

            Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\]=)(\[.+?\])");

            string[] results = r.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**BONUS** - convert to `int[][]` if you are fancy.

```
int[][] ints = results.Select(p => p.Split(new [] {'[', ',', ']'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Where(s => { int temp; return int.TryParse(s, out temp);}) //omits the '...' match from your sample. potentially you could change the regex pattern to only catch digits but that isnt what you wanted (i dont think)
                .Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: You don't need to use a capturing group when you're retrieving the whole matched substring.  You'll find it in `matchObj.Groups[0].Value`, but since `Groups[0]` refers to to the Match object itself, you can just say `matchObj.Value`.  (ref: [Match Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx), in the Remarks section).

Comment: @AlanMoore I prefer to be explicit where reasonable. I find it prevents nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be an option, but it would be a bit complicated. Assuming you don't have a parser for your input, you can try the following:

-Split the string by `;` characters, and you'd get a string array (e.g. `string[]`):
"array[0]=[1,2,3,4,5,6]", "array[1]=[1,2,4,6,2,8]", "array[2]=[...]". Let's call it `list`.

Then for each of the elements in that array (assuming the input is in order), do this:
-Find the index of `]=`, let that be `x`.
-Take the substring of your whole string from the starting index `x + 2`. Let's call it `sub`.
-Assign the result string as the current string in your array, e.g. if you are iterating with a regular `for` loop, and your indexing variable is `i` such as `for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){...}`:

`list[i] = sub`.

I know it is a dirty and an error-prone solution, e.g. if input is `array[0] =[1,2...` instead of `array[0]=[1,2,...` it won't work due to the extra space there, but if your input mathces that *exact* pattern (no extra spaces, no newlines etc), it will do the job.

**UPDATE:** cosset's answer seems to be the most practical and easiest way to achieve your result, especially if you are familiar with LINQ.

Comment: Regex is only complicated if you are unfamiliar. If you have an IDE for it on your desktop/browser then the task is easier still.

Comment: yes, and many people, even many programmers (including me) are really unfamiliar with regex. (i mean, it's definitely a good thing to know, but it takes time and i have other priorities) can you recommend any good free regex ide or website then?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] output=Regex.Matches(input,@"(?<!array)\[.*?\]")
                     .Cast<Match>()
                     .Select(x=>x.Value)
                     .ToArray();
```

**OR**

```
string[] output=Regex.Split(input,@";?array[\d+]=");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "array[0]=[1,a,3,4,asdf54,6];array[1]=[1aaa,2,4,k=6,2,8];array[2]=[2,3,2,3,2,3=3k3k]";
string[] m1 = str.Split(';');
List<string> m3 = new List<string>();
foreach (string ms in m1)
{
    string[] m2 = ms.Split('=');
    m3.Add(m2[1]);
}
```

Comment: This answer has the same problem as [cosset's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19112699/20938); you need to limit that second Split: `ms.Split(new Char[] {'='}, 2)`